# Magnetic field felt by an observer "orbiting" a proton

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, particle-physics, magnetic-fields

Classically, if one has an electron orbiting a proton, how can the magnetic field felt by an observer with the same instantaneous velocity as the electron be calculated? It seems that I may find the magnetic field felt by this observer by boosting the proton to the same frame as the electron at some instant, and then calculating the B-field generated by transforming the E-field of the proton in the rest frame. Is this not the correct reasoning? If not, why so?

Comment: I think the reasoning would be flawed because, assuming the electron follows a circular "orbit" (which is not close to what happens in reality), an observer at rest with respect to the electron wouldn't be in an inertial reference frame.

Comment: If we look instantaneously though it would be an inertial frame I believe.

Comment: Classically there's no way that the electron isn't going to fall into the proton. If you assume that by some magic it has a stable orbit, it will still radiate an EM field which shouldn't be too hard to calculate for large distances (compared to the distance proton-electron).

Comment: This comes from a more finely worded question, which asks "what an observer moving with the same instantaneous velocity as the electron, at the same position" would feel. In this case, we can ignore the magic of the electron orbiting and pursue the hypothetical question soundly I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proton's reference frame there is a magnetic field produced by the moving electron, and an electric field produced by both the proton and the electron.

If you boost to the electron's instantaneous reference frame, you have to transform the proton's position and velocity to this frame, and also transform the fields (mentioned above) to this frame.

Comment: So, how big is the B field as seen by the proton in (say) a hydrogen atom (I'll leave uranium as a exercise for the reader, as all good textbooks say...)

Comment: $\textbf{B}  = -\mu_0 /4 \pi e \textbf{v}\times \textbf{ r}/r^3 $ where $\bf v$ is the electron velocity and $\bf r$ is the vector pointing from the proton to the electron.